# SQLMetal reference loop

Tags: c#, serialization, linq-to-sql

I'm using SQL Metal to access my MSSQL Server via C# and LINQ to SQL. When having foreign keys in the database it automatically adds the referenced object as attribute to the class which is awesome. But the problem is that it also does that on the referenced type and creates a reference loop this way which restrains me from serializing my classes. Are there any options of doing the references only one way?

Comment: Is it an option for you, to modify the classes? If so, you could set the attribute `[NonSerialized]` to the foreign key property of the referenced type.

Comment: Yes, `[XmlIgnore]` did the trick. The last problem to solve is how to make the attribute added automatically so I don't have to redo it everytime my database changes